# Conducting Search in Outlook Inbox through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I get a runtime error when trying to run my code: I'm basically trying to click a button in my excel file, which will then search through my inbox for "Acting Assignment".

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutSearch As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim fldr As String
Dim subjekt As String
fldr = "Inbox"
subjekt = "Acting Assignment"
Set OutSearch = OutApp.Advancedsearch(fldr, subjekt, "True", "My search")
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I get the following error on the set OutSearch line. How can I repair this code to run a search? Thanks for your help. 
[image: error]

Comment: And like this `Set OutSearch = OutApp.Advancedsearch(fldr, subjekt, True, "My search")` ? I changed `True` in boolean you entered it as string

Comment: @ThomasG this doesn't mitigate the error. I still get the same message, any further advice? This would be a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to format your search filter like this :

```
subjekt = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = 'Acting Assignment'"
```